# Return dynamic generic Type

Tags: swift, generics

**Fixed in Swift 4.1**

*The problem described below is fixed in Swift 4.1 see Hamish's comment*

**Problem**

I get a runtime error on this code:

```
class A: Decodable{
    let a: Int
}

class B: A{
    let b: Int = 1 // side problem 2: class B has no initializers. 
                   //Why? It conforms to Decodable right??
}

func getType() -> A.Type{
    return B.self
}

class Test: UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let data = ["a": 100, "b": 200]
        let jsonData =  try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data)
        let t =         try! JSONDecoder().decode(getType(), from: jsonData)
        print((t as! B).b) //run-time
    }
}
```

Because t is not a B. Strange, I return a `B.self`. If I print `getType()`, I get this: `MyProject.B`, so although in my method signature I return a A.Type, it should be a B.type since my print statement says so.

I get exactly the same print value when I remove the call `getType()` and directly place B.self. And than I do **not** get a run-time error.

What is the difference between the two ways? Why does way 2, in which I directly type B.self works, and  my first way does not, although the value from the print statements says the value of way 1 and way 2 are the same.

Comment: This is a known bug (https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5928) which is fixed in Swift 4.1 – in Swift 4.1, the decoder will decode a `B`.

Comment: @Hamish YES :) Thank you for letting me know!!

Answer (score 0):

`JSONDecoder.decode()` is a generic function, and generics get resolved at runtime. This means that the runtime behaviour of `getType()` is not used, and the compiler relies solely on the function declaration.

On a side note, `Decodable` needs a concrete type to work with, a type chosen at compile time, because it needs to know which decoding containers to use.

You can obtain some dynamic behaviour if you do some static processing of the types:

```
func decode(from data: Data, type: A.Type) throws {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if type == A.self { return try decoder.decode(data, type: A.self) }
    else if type == B.self { return try decoder.decode(data, type: B.self) }
    else { throw TypeNotSupportedError }
}
```

Basically at some point you need to give a concrete type to the decoder.

Regarding error #2, it seems the compiler auto-generates the `Codable` support only one hierarchy level.

Comment: Is there any way to make it dynamic?

Comment: @J.Doe I don't think you can make it dynamic with `Codable`. But do you really need to make it dynamic?

Comment: Well I got a lot of objects conforming to a superclass which is Decodable. If the method can be dynamic, this saves me so many lines of repeating code, just to change the type of the object.

Comment: @J.Doe I updated my answer with a possible solution. Not quite nice, though

Comment: yes haha this was my backup solution as well.. hmm I am trying to find an other way but I can not find any :(

Comment: @J.Doe the edit you just made on the question kinda qualified it for closing it. Basically, if the solution is to use Swift 4.1, then this would deserve an answer not an edit on the question. A question that contains its solution is no longer a question.